# Spawn block based on score

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a endless runner game, and have a question.

How can i make the blocks spawn faster based on the current score. The higher the score is, the faster the blocks spawn.

Block Spawn Code:

```
blockStatuses["block1"] = BlockStatus(isRunning: false, timeGapForNextRun: random(), currentInterval: UInt32(0))
```

Random() code:

```
func random() -> UInt32 {
        var range = arc4random_uniform(50)
        return range
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about adding the current `score` as a parameter of your `random` method?

```
func random(yourScore: yourScoreType) -> UInt32 {
    var range = arc4random_uniform((UInt32)(50 - k * yourScore))  // k is a constant
    return range
}
```